# XSLT 2.0: filter on match

Tags: xslt-2.0

```
<xsl:template match="lat:entry[document(lat:file)//h2]"/>
```

Is this template called ONLY on "entry" elements that contain a lat:file tag with a file name, which file contains h2 tags?
Or on ANY lat:entry ?
If the latter, how can I construct a correct match? (correct being the former option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That match pattern `lat:entry[document(lat:file)//h2]` indeed matches elements with local name `entry` with the namespace matched by the prefix `lat` which have one or more `file` child element in the same namespace where `document(lat:file)` finds at least one XML document containing `h2` elements (in no namespace or in the xpath-default-namespace, depending on the context). So your first description is kind of right, with the exception that `document(lat:file)//h2` could result in several documents being loaded and checked for `h2` elements, if there are several `lat:file` child elements.

Comment: Thank you. And your exception does not apply, because entry has one and only one file.